# Индексация в google

Tags: google-search, sitemap

У меня есть генератор сайтмап, который каждые N дней генерирует новый файл sitemap.xml, после чего я отправляю его на индексацию в google. Но, есть странная особенность: количество проиндексированных URL более 500, однако, в "статусе индексирования" (google webmaster) пишет, что проиндексировано 0.

[image]

Просьба подсказать, с чем это связано? (Быть может, не нужно каждый раз отправлять заново sitemap?)

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно каждый раз отсылать. Гугл сам найдёт этот файл.

Answer (score 0):

Раздел "*Статус индексирования*" обновляется каждые 7 дней, а раздел "*Sitemap*" каждый день.

Данные могут не успевать подтягиваться.

Или не обновляйте так часто, или создавайте sitemap1.xml, sitemap2.xml, и т.д.

Примерно количество проиндексированных страниц вы можете увидет используя оператор поиска **site:**

`site:https://доменное имя`